# Multi SQL queries or joins?

Tags: sql-server, performance

I have a table `SpecialOffers` and table for special offer items called `SOItems`
And i want to get the special offer for a specific item if i found it so first i did this :

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM SOTtems WHERE ItemType = 2 AND Itemid = @id)
BEGIN
      INSERT INTO #SO
      SELECT * FROM SpecialOffers so 
      INNER JOIN SOItems soi ON so.Id = soi.SpecialOfferID
      WHERE soi.ItemType = 2 AND soi.Itemid = @id
END
```

But then to get rid of INNER JOIN because i thought it's better for performance i did this :

```
DECLARE @specialOfferID INT

SET @specialOfferID = (SELECT SpecialOfferID FROM SOTtems WHERE ItemType = 2 AND Itemid = @id)

IF @specialOfferID IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
     INSERT INTO #SO
     SELECT * FROM SpecialOffers so 
     WHERE ID = @specialOfferID
END
```

So which is more efficient and better for performance to execute more sql queries or use join for this example and in general

Note : in the stored procedure i am writing i have to this more than 6 times that is why i asked u :)

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This hand optimization is likely unnecessary, since the optimizer is more than capable of handling this.

You can put both into SSMS and run them together and look at relative costs in the the execution plan.

Avoiding joins is not usually a first step in optimizing.

My first step is usually to look at the indexing strategy and ensure I haven't left out the basic indexes and then look at execution plans and see if there are any glaring problems.

Then I don't optimize until I have an actual performance problem - and then only after understanding what's really causing the performance issue.

I would actually simplify it down to only:

```
INSERT INTO #SO
SELECT *
FROM SpecialOffers so 
INNER JOIN SOItems soi
    ON so.Id = soi.SpecialOfferID
    AND soi.ItemType = 2
    AND soi.Itemid = @id
```

That's it - no EXISTS check or anything else - the inner join means that the check for existence is redundant, because this won't insert anything otherwise.  This makes for more maintainable code in one sense, because you won't need to duplicate the condition if it changes, and code in a join is not likely to be altered accidentally.  On the other hand, if the join does get altered, it could have more serious repercussions.

Note, you can still write this as a WHERE version without using the EXISTS check as well.

Less code typically means less places for bugs to hide.

Comment: Thanks a lot i agree with you, but i don't optimize until i have a performance problem that i don't agree, I mean if you write your code better at first you will not have a performance problems in future, then you don't have to optimize

Comment: @TheDarkLord The code needs to work correctly first, be maintainable and meet basic best practices.  Everything after that is optimization.  But you're right, after many (14, maybe?) years with SQL Server, my definition of basic best practices is usually sufficient to avoid much further optimization.

Comment: @TheDarkLord I re-read your question and modified my answer to show exactly what I would do.

Answer (score 1):

Past both the queries in a window in Management Studio, and display the execution plan for the query. That will tell you exactly what's happening.

Most likely you will see that there is very little performance difference. What might make the second somewhat faster is that it doesn't have the `IF EXISTS(...)`, but on the other hand that result would be cached, so the difference is still small.

Another thing that can make a difference, is that you are putting more data into the `#SO` table with the first query. As you are using `SELECT *`, you are getting more data than you need. For example, both the fields `SOItems.SpecialOfferID` and `SpecialOffers.Id` are included, but you know that they are always the same. Specify what fields you want returned, so that you don't fetch more than you need.

Comment: Yes thanks, actually i am not using SELECT * in real code but i write it here so i don't have to write the names of fields :)

Comment: @TheDarkLord: Good to hear. :)